# Как получить нужный объект json java?

Tags: java, android, json

Как получить данные с поля name? Не могу понять как перемещаться.

```
{
  "response": {
    "GeoObjectCollection": {
      "metaDataProperty": {
        "GeocoderResponseMetaData": {
          "request": "N52.076005,E23.723004",
          "found": "8",
          "results": "1",
          "Point": {
            "pos": "23.723004 52.076005"
          }
        }
      },
      "featureMember": [
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "kind": "house",
                "text": "Беларусь, Брест, улица Морозова, 5",
                "precision": "exact",
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Брест, улица Морозова, 5",
                    "CountryNameCode": "BY",
                    "CountryName": "Беларусь",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Брестская область",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Брест",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "улица Морозова",
                          "Premise": {
                            "PremiseNumber": "5"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "description": "Брест, Беларусь",
            "name": "улица Морозова, 5",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "23.714535 52.070874",
                "upperCorner": "23.730992 52.081015"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "23.722764 52.075945"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй для работы с JSON попользоваться библиотекой GSON, и переводить JSON сразу в объект, избавишь себя от всех этих проблем с JSONObject и JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил свой вопрос таким методом:

```
String responseData = response.body().string();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);
JSONObject response_json = json.getJSONObject("response");
JSONObject GeoObjectCollection = response_json.getJSONObject("GeoObjectCollection");
JSONArray featureMember = GeoObjectCollection.getJSONArray("featureMember");
JSONObject featureMember2 = featureMember.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject GeoObject = featureMember2.getJSONObject("GeoObject");

final String owner = GeoObject.getString("name");
```

Comment: плохая практика использовать захардкоженые индексы ```.get(123)``` + цифири в названии переменных, которые рушат понимание кода (```something123```). если вам важен не только name из объекта, то можете с помощью библиотеки ```gson``` собрать удобный POJO